# Survival regression with survival package in R

Tags: r, survival-analysis

We are actually trying to reproduce the results of a model in R, which has been coded in SAS. The model looks as follows: ln(Duration)=X'B+S*e, where X is the matrix of 10 independent variables, B a vector of coefficients, S is the scale parameter and e the error term.

The data set we use [is here](http://www.drvkumar.com/books/25/Statistical-Methods-in-Customer-Relationship-Management)

There you can find the SAS code as well.

The first try looked as follows:

```
Dur <- survreg(Surv(Duration, Censor==0) ~ Acq_Expense + Acq_Expense_SQ + Ret_Expense +  Ret_Expense_SQ + Crossbuy + Frequency + Frequency_SQ + Industry + Revenue + Employees, dist='weibull', data = daten [daten$Acquisition==1, ])
summary(Dur)
```

But the coefficients in this model are not correct. On the [following picture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i5z5yqdternbmfo/Output%20R%20and%20SAS.PNG) you see the R output on the left and the correct SAS output on the right:

[image]

We detected a problem with the squared terms (Acq_Expense_SQ, Ret_Expense_SQ), because when we exclude those terms all other estimates are much closer to the correct values. Therefore, we tried to scale down the squared terms by the factor 0.001.

```
    Acq_Expense_SQ2 <- data.frame(0.001*daten$Acq_Expense_SQ)
    colnames(Acq_Expense_SQ2) <- c("Acq_Expense_SQ2")
    daten["Acq_Expense_SQ2"] <- Acq_Expense_SQ2
    date3 <- subset(daten, daten$Acquisition==1)

    Ret_Expense_SQ2 <- data.frame(0.001*daten$Ret_Expense_SQ)
    colnames(Ret_Expense_SQ2) <- c("Ret_Expense_SQ2")
    daten["Ret_Expense_SQ2"] <- Ret_Expense_SQ2
    date3 <- subset(daten, daten$Acquisition==1)

    Dur <- survreg(Surv(Duration, Censor == 0, type = 'right') ~ Acq_Expense + Acq_Expense_SQ2 + Ret_Expense + Ret_Expense_SQ2 + Crossbuy + Frequency + Frequency_SQ + Industry + Revenue + Employees, dist='weibull', scale = 0, data = date3)
    summary(Dur)
```

Now, the coefficient are much closer to the correct ones, but I do not know why.
Is there a possible explanation for this problem?
Or do you see another problem with our code?

Comment: Read the `?survreg.distributions` help page to find how the Weibull distribution is parametrized in the survival package. (And if you need further help with that issue there are many similar answers over the years from Terry Therneau that are in the Rhelp Archives and I suspect that some of them are to questions about why R estimated coefficients are not the same as from SAS.)

Comment: The other issue that arises with the use of squared (or cubed) terms is that the naively calculated values are not independent of the linear terms. You would need to center and perhaps scale to avoid issues with lack of independence. The `poly` function is designed to avoid those issues that may affect inferential validity.